# I never thought I would find the courage

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

As a matter of fact, I never thought I would find the courage and the nerve to post a puzzle like this one.
If it doesn't get me stoned, it will get me downvoted by myopic people.
I hope that some of you might find it worth their precious while to throw a bit of thinking at it.
There is a hidden pattern in this paragraph, and I was quite amused when I first saw it.
Please don't assume that I am writing horrid nonsense or that my mind has fallen asleep.
Look meticulously for related words that have been altered in some odd way.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Any chance that hidden pattern isn't very pronounced?

> Each sentence seems to contain an anagram of one of the words showing up in that sentence.

More precisely:

> never - nerve
>  doesn't - stoned
>  worth - throw
>  was - saw
>  please - asleep
>  related - altered